# Есть ли смысл повторного вызова write на дескриптор tcp сокета, если после первого вызова была отправлена только часть данных?

Tags: linux, c, tcp

Есть ли смысл повторного вызова write на дескриптор tcp сокета, если после первого вызова была отправлена только часть данных? Т.е мы передаем wrie что необходимо отправить 100 байт, но write вернул 80, есть ли смысл в попытке доотправить 20 байт повторным вызовом write?

Comment: Если эти данные нужны, то да, нужно аккуратно дослать 20 байт.

Comment: `write` возвращает не число байтов, отправленных в сеть, а число байтов, записанных в буфер. TCP постарается доставить всё, что есть в буфере, но то, чего в буфере нет, в сеть не попадёт. Поэтому таки да, оставшиеся 20 байтов нужно записать в дескриптор.